# ForwardedHeaderFilter no longer support IPv6

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, ipv6, x-forwarded-for

After upgrading spring boot version to 2.4.9, the spring boot application works fine only for ipv4 but throws an error for ipv6. The app is deployed on google cloud run service. Current versions:

```
      <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-gcp-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.3</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
```

```
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.9</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
```

Error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid IPv4 address: 2409:4042:2319:a971:c4db:4661:939c:443b
    at org.springframework.web.util.UriComponentsBuilder.parseForwardedFor(UriComponentsBuilder.java:363)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter$ForwardedHeaderExtractingRequest.<init>(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:246)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.ForwardedHeaderFilter.doFilterInternal(ForwardedHeaderFilter.java:149)
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:119)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:190)
```

I was able to find a similar issue but did not find any solution.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/issues/26748

The line in the code that throws the error
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/6c68419073b43fb29114a3af4e402c729084ed84/spring-web/src/main/java/org/springframework/web/util/UriComponentsBuilder.java#L363

Comment: To check if an IP is v6, I use the following quick-and-dirty code: `(InetAddress.getByName(ipStr) instanceof Inet6Address)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is due to google cloud run service not respecting RFC7239 standards and not due to spring boot. Cloud run fails to enclose IPv6 addresses with quotes and square brackets(as per RFC7239 standards) due to which spring interprets it as an IPv4 address and fails while parsing port number from the address.

This is very strange that google cloud fails to follow the standard. As of today, the Google cloud team says they are working on the fix but ETA is not guaranteed.

You can track the status here:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184230536?pli=1

Comment: You're correct about the problem but incorrect about this being an RFC 7239 violation: XFF doesn't have a spec and there are incompatible implementations in the wild. The `Forwarded` header was created to standardize this and similar problems with XFF as per the RFC:

> Note that IPv6 addresses may not be quoted in X-Forwarded-For and may not be enclosed by square brackets, but they are quoted and enclosed in square brackets in "Forwarded".

Comment: The Google Cloud team fixed this issue. See: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/184230536?pli=1 for Details.